# Compactness in topology of uniform conergence (of functions and all their derivatives) on compact subsets of (0,\infty)

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, compactness

I am trying to understand an example in the book "Lectures on Choquet's Theorem" (R.R. Phelps). My question is:

Given the space of real valued infinitely differentiable functions on $(0, \infty)$ equipped with the topology of uniform convergence (of functions and all their derivatives) on compact subsets of $(0, \infty)$.

This topology can be given with the following (countable family) pseudonorms:

$$p_{m,n}(f) = \sup \{|f^{(k)}(x) | : m^{-1} \leq x \leq m, 0 \leq k \leq n \}$$

(with $m,n = 1,2,3,\ldots$).

The author points out, that in this space a set is compact if the set is bounded and closed. This fact can be shown with Ascoli's Theorem (according to the author).

Could somebody outline the way of proving this? Is the goal to show that boundedness implies equicontinuity? I've only seen proofs of Ascoli's Theorem on continuous functions on compact sets.